# master page problem

Tags: asp.net

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="Main.master.vb" Inherits="Main" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="CSS_Styles/twoColFixLtHdr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function callAlert(msg) {
             alert(msg);
         }
    </script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="header">

      &nbsp;<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" 
                                             ForeColor="White" 
                                             CssClass="signin"  Font-Size="Small"/>
          <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
          <AnonymousTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
                                         CssClass="register" 
                                         ForeColor="White" 
                                         NavigateUrl="~/login.aspx" Font-Size="Small">Register</asp:HyperLink>


          </AnonymousTemplate>
          <LoggedInTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" 
                                         NavigateUrl="~/account.aspx" 
                                         ForeColor="White" 
                                         CssClass="myaccount" Font-Size="Small">My Account</asp:HyperLink>
          <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" 
                                         NavigateUrl="~/fleaMarket/fleaMarketAccount.aspx" 
                                         ForeColor="White" 
                                         CssClass="fleaaccount" Font-Size="Small">Flea Account</asp:HyperLink>

          <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" 
                                         NavigateUrl="~/admin/access/access_rule_summary.aspx" 
                                         ForeColor="White" 
                                         CssClass="myaccount" Visible="false" Font-Size="Small">Admin</asp:HyperLink>
          <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" 
                                         NavigateUrl="~/report.aspx" 
                                         ForeColor="White" 
                                         CssClass="myaccount" Visible="false" Font-Size="Small">Report</asp:HyperLink>                                                        

          </LoggedInTemplate>
          </asp:LoginView>                                   
                  <br />

                  <div id="CartAr">
                      <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Width="300px" Height="82px" BackColor="#ffffff">
                          <asp:Image ID="imgShpngCrt" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/cart image1.jpg" Width="90px" Height="82px" CssClass="fltlft1" />
                          <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView2" runat="server">
                          <AnonymousTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"  
                                 ForeColor="Black" 
                                 CssClass="" Font-Size="Small">Welcome!Guest.
                          </asp:Label>
                          </AnonymousTemplate>
                          <LoggedInTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"  
                                 ForeColor="Black" 
                                 CssClass="" Font-Size="Small">Welcome! <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName2" runat="server" />
                          </asp:Label>       
                          </LoggedInTemplate>
                          </asp:LoginView><br />
                          <div style="float:left; font-size:small;">
                          <asp:Label ID="lblCartItem" runat="server" Text="Items in your cart :" ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
                          </div>
                          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelMaster" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
                          <ContentTemplate>
                          <div style="float:left; font-size:small;">
                              <asp:Label ID="lblcartitemcount" runat="server" Text="hahahah"></asp:Label>
                          </div>    
                          </ContentTemplate>
                          </asp:UpdatePanel>
                          <br /><br />
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" ForeColor="#336699" CssClass="textdeco" Font-Size="Small">View Cart</asp:LinkButton>
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          </asp:Panel>



                  </div>




    <!-- end .header --></div>
<div id="navPos">
    <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
  <li>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="Home" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/index.aspx">Home&nbsp;&nbsp;|</asp:HyperLink>
  </li>
  <li>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="Products" runat="server" CssClass="MenuBarItemSubmenu">Products</asp:HyperLink>
      <ul>
      <li><asp:HyperLink ID="Groceries" runat="server">Groceries</asp:HyperLink></li>
      <li><asp:HyperLink ID="DepartmentalItems" runat="server">Departmental Items</asp:HyperLink></li>
      <li><asp:HyperLink ID="Electronics" runat="server">Electronics</asp:HyperLink>
      <ul>
      <li><asp:HyperLink ID="Mobiles" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/itemsDisplayPage_aspx/itemsDisplayPage.aspx?typeOfItem=mobiles">Mobiles</asp:HyperLink></li>
      <li><asp:HyperLink ID="Laptops" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/itemsDisplayPage_aspx/itemsDisplayPage.aspx?typeOfItem=computers">Laptops &amp; Computers</asp:HyperLink></li>
      <li><asp:HyperLink ID="Accessories" runat="server">Accessories</asp:HyperLink></li>
      </ul>      
      </li>
      <li><asp:HyperLink ID="Kitchen" runat="server">Kitchen Items</asp:HyperLink></li>
      <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" runat="server">Home Appliances</asp:HyperLink></li>
      <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink7" runat="server">Fasion</asp:HyperLink></li>
    </ul>     
  </li>
  <li><asp:HyperLink ID="AboutUs" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Restaurant.aspx">|&nbsp;&nbsp;Restaurant Offers&nbsp;&nbsp;|</asp:HyperLink></li>
  <li><asp:LinkButton ID="cmdMedicine" runat="server">Buy Medicines&nbsp;&nbsp;|</asp:LinkButton></li>
  <li><asp:HyperLink ID="FleaMarket" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/fleaMarket/fleaBazaar.aspx">Flea Market&nbsp;&nbsp;|</asp:HyperLink></li>
  <li><asp:HyperLink ID="SellItems" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/fleaMarket/hostItem.aspx">Sell Items&nbsp;&nbsp;|</asp:HyperLink></li>
  <li><asp:HyperLink ID="WhyUS" runat="server">Why Us&nbsp;&nbsp;|</asp:HyperLink></li>
  <li><asp:HyperLink ID="Payment" runat="server">Payment&nbsp;&nbsp;|</asp:HyperLink></li>
  <li><asp:HyperLink ID="Contact_Us" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/ContactUs.aspx">Contact Us</asp:HyperLink></li>

</ul>


    </div><br /><br />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 <div class="footer">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubscribe" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdSubscribe" runat="server" Text="Subscribe" /><br />
  <div style="text-align:center; font-size:small;">
   <a href="#">About Us</a>&nbsp;|<a href="#">Payment Options</a>&nbsp;|<a href="#">Terms &amp; 
      Conditions</a>&nbsp;|<a href="#">Return Policy </a>&nbsp;|<a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;©TriceDeals.Com 
      2011.
    </div>
    <!-- end .footer --></div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="AfterFooter" runat="server">


  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", { imgDown: "SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif", imgRight: "SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif" });
</script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my master page...i have a drop down navigation in my site which i have placed in master page...so now the problem is "the dropdown property of the navigation menu works properly in some of the pages and does not work in some oter...why does this happen??if i do not use the master page the menu work in all the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the tilde(~) to get the root-directory of your application, because some page might be in sub-directories and therefore have another relative path to the Styles/Scripts than other pages(@Aristos solution only works for first-level subdirectories).

You can use `~` only on server-controls, so add a `runat=server` on your link-tags:

```
<link runat="server" href="~/CSS_Styles/twoColFixLtHdr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link runat="server" hef="~/SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

To get the correct reference to your script-files you have to add ScriptReferences:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
   <Scripts>
      <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" />
   </Scripts>
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```